# epublib Epub Library build issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, epublib

I am trying to work with the epublib code base. I think I have my maven file set up correctly. The dependencies do get downloaded and are in my .m2 folder. However, I can not get maven build to complete without errors.

I have used 
    mvn install,
    mvn clean install,
    mvn package,

if I take out the epublib dependencies everything works.So what did I miss when I set up my pom file? Or what other way can I use the epublib libraries.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>epub</groupId>
<artifactId>epubfix</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>EPub file Correction</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF- 
 8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.siegmann.epublib</groupId>
        <artifactId>epublib-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.siegmann.epublib</groupId>
        <artifactId>epublib-tools</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.siegmann.epublib</groupId>
        <artifactId>epublib-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </project>


I expect to see something like 

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Building EPub file Correction 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) 
 @ epubfix ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ 
epubfix ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default- 
testResources) @ epubfix ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
/Users/dyk/Eclipse/workspace/epub/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default- 
testCompile) @ epubfix ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ 
epubfix ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory:     
/Users/dyk/Eclipse/workspace/epub/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ epubfix ---
[INFO] Building jar: 
/Users/dyk/Eclipse/workspace/epub/target/epubfix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] META-INF/maven/epub/epubfix/pom.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/epub/epubfix/pom.properties already added, 
skipping
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.269 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-12T10:57:11-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 

However, I am getting this error.

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EPub file Correction 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/siegmann/epublib/epublib- 
core/3.1/epublib-core-3.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib-core:jar:3.1 is         
 missing, no 
dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/siegmann/epublib/epublib- 
tools/3.1/epublib-tools-3.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib-tools:jar:3.1 is 
missing, no 
dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/siegmann/epublib/epublib- 
parent/3.1/epublib-parent-3.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib-parent:pom:3.1 is 
missing, no 
dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/siegmann/epublib/epublib- 
core/3.1/epublib-core-3.1.jar
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/siegmann/epublib/epublib- 
tools/3.1/epublib-tools-3.1.jar
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.293 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-12T10:11:37-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project epubfix: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project epub:epubfix:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The 
following 
artifacts could not be resolved: nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib- 
core:jar:3.1, 
nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib-tools:jar:3.1, 
nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib- 
parent:pom:3.1: Could not find artifact nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib- 
core:jar:3.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> 
[Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug 
logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible 
solutions, please         
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Comment: Please add the errors to your question.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project epubfix: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project epub:epubfix:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The 
following 
artifacts could not be resolved: nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib- 
core:jar:3.1, 
nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib-tools:jar:3.1, 
nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib- 
parent:pom:3.1: Could not find artifact nl.siegmann.epublib:epublib- 
core:jar:3.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Answer (score 0):

The dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.siegmann.epublib</groupId>
    <artifactId>epublib-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

is not in MavenCentral. You need to configure the correct repository (or, if this is a spelling error, correct it).

Comment: Okay thanks so when I get the dependency from mvnrepository.com  to add to my pom file I need to look for the Compile Dependencies at the bottom of the page. Maven does not automatically pull those in. They also need to be in my pom.xml file also. Thanks.